# Letter counter with list

Tags: python

I am currently trying to make a letter counter using lists. The goal of the function is to count how many characters are in each string, then print how many strings have a length of 4. I'm having a little trouble, and I'm hoping for some help. I am very new to python so I apologize if the answer is very simple, or if I missed a colon or something.

```
def count_4let(letter_list):

    if letter_list == len(4):
                counter+=1

    print("The number of words with the length of 4 is", counter)

letter_list = ["Whos","the","leader","of","the","club","thats","made","for","you","and","me","M I C K E Y","M O U S E"]
#main
print(count_4let(letter_list))
```

Comment: `sum(1 for word in letter_list if len(word) == 4)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the elements of the list. You call `len()` on each element, not `len(4)`.

You also need to initialize the `counter` variable before you can add to it.

The function should just return the count, not print anything. The printing is done by the caller.

```
def count_4let(word_list):
    counter = 0
    for word in word_list:
        if len(word) == 4:
            counter += 1
    return counter

letter_list = ["Whos","the","leader","of","the","club","thats","made","for","you","and","me","M I C K E Y","M O U S E"]
#main
print("The number of words with length 4 is", count_4let(letter_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sum` function with a generator expression that outputs whether a given word in the list has a length of 4:

```
def count_4let(letter_list):
    return sum(len(word) == 4 for word in letter_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with `map()` and `count()`

```
>>> l = ["whos", "the", "leader", "of", "the", "club", "thats", "made", "for", "you", "and", "me", "M I C K E Y", "M O U S E"]
>>> list(map(len, l)).count(4)
3
```

Answer (score 0):

first you shouldn't be writing the length of a number, cause think about it that just doesn't make sense:

```
def count_4let(letter_list):
  if len(letter_list) == 4:
    counter += 1
print("The number of words with the length of 4 is", counter)

letter_list ["Whos", "the", "leader", "of", "the", "club", "thats", "made", "for", "you"," and", "me", "M I C K E Y", "M O U S E"]
print(count_4let(letter_list))
```